# Almacenar datos de un archivo csv a una lista enlazada simple en c++

Tags: c++, lista, csv

Al iniciar el programa tengo que leer y almacenar los datos de un archivo CSV en una Lista Enlazada Simple y no se como puedo hacerlo, contiene estos datos

```
fecha;codigo_hospital;numero_de_cama
20210101;17;122
20210101;14;218
20210101;15;127
20210101;16;122
20210101;17;122
```

Por favor si es que alguien me puede decir como hacerlo, estoy muy perdido):

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con leer y almacenar? ¿Tienes que almacenar la línea entera o separar la línea? ¿Se queda como texto o debes convertirlo a número? ¿Lo almacenas en un objeto o en tres listas separadas? ¿Es una lista estándar o una lista creada por ti?

Comment: Osea se lee archivo en programa para poder almacenar su contenido en la memoria, es que la instruccion dice esto: 

leeProcesa(string, Lista): Al iniciarse la ejecución del programa, este invoca a la función leeProcesa que leerá el contenido del archivo CSV y almacenará su contenido completo en la memoria utilizando para su
almacenamiento una lista de tipo LLS.

eso es lo que no se como hacer ):

Comment: Nada de lo que me has escrito responde ninguna de mis preguntas.